# Javascript on the RPI: GPIOCtrl is not a function

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi

Hi all I am trying to create a door lock using the following

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");
var gpioPin = 4; 
var isOpened=false; 
var unlock = function(){ 
if(!isOpened){
/* Open the door lock */
gpio.write(gpioPin, 1, function() {
isOpened = true;
});
/*Lock door in 2 seconds*/
setTimeout(function () {
gpio.write(gpioPin, 0, function() {
isOpened = false;
});
}, 2000);}}
```

then the following:

```
var http = require('http'); var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var GPIOCtrl = require('./controller.js');
app.get('/unlock/', function(req, res){ 
GPIOCtrl.unlock();
});
app.listen(3000); 
console.log('App Server running at port 3000');
```

When I run the program I get the message app server running at port 3000, however when I call it I get the following message:

```
TypeError: GPIOCtrl.unlock is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [export](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) your module as following in your `controller.js` :

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio"),
  gpioPin = 4,
  isOpened = false,

module.exports = {
  unlock: function() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      /* Open the door lock */
      gpio.write(gpioPin, 1, function() {
        isOpened = true;
      });

      /*Lock door in 2 seconds*/
      setTimeout(function() {
        gpio.write(gpioPin, 0, function() {
          isOpened = false;
        });
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I just changed that and got past that error. Now I get Error: Pin number isn&#39;t valid

Comment: @ShanePitts Yes, it's because `GPIO 4` is used for power supply according to the [pinout](https://pinout.xyz/)

Comment: So according to that chart I would want to input 7 since i am connected to BCM 4?

Comment: I'm sorry very new to using the Pi

Comment: @ShanePitts Yes. Try it, and you'll see :)